# If a Deployment in K8s creates replicas and a ReplicaSet, for you what is the point of creating a ReplicationController?

Tags: kubernetes

In the Kubernetes website it mentions

> The following is an example of a Deployment. It creates a ReplicaSet
> to bring up three nginx Pods:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
```

If it creates a ReplicaSet for you then for what reason would we create a new ReplicationController? Is that not duplicating something that exists?

I could just be confused as I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReplicationController`'s updated version is `ReplicaSet`. `ReplicaSet` is considered as a replacement of replication controller. The key difference between the replica set and the replication controller is: replication controller only supports equality-based selector whereas the replica set supports set-based selector.

As far the k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) : ReplicaSet is the next-generation ReplicationController that supports the new set-based label selector. It's mainly used by Deployment as a mechanism to orchestrate pod creation, deletion and updates. Note that we recommend using Deployments instead of directly using Replica Sets, unless you require custom update orchestration or don't require updates at all.

Comment: Totally didn't see that doc. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll accept this.